# TableView data does not get updated with NSOperation

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nsoperation

So I'm not sure if I set this up correctly.  I have a `SearchDisplayController` and search bar.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 44)];
    self.SearchEntry = searchBar;
    self.SearchEntry.tintColor = DARKGRAY_COLOR;
    self.SearchEntry.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    self.SearchEntry.delegate = self;
    UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayCtlr = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchEntry contentsController:self];
    self.SearchController = searchDisplayCtlr;
```

These go inside a `UIToolbar`.  Because querying the database for certain values can take awhile, I took code out and put it in an `NSOperation` subclass.  At the end, it calls back the ViewController through a delegate to update the actual data:

```
[self.searchOperationDelegate searchDidFinishWithResults:self.searchResults];
```

So when actual typing goes in my search bar, I do this:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (_queue.operationCount > 0) {
        [_queue cancelAllOperations];
    }

    SearchOperation *search = [[SearchOperation alloc] initWithSearchText:searchText];
    search.searchOperationDelegate = self;
    [self.queue addOperation:search];
}
```

I am basically canceling any previous search and only searching on what is currently in the `searchText` string.

And then in my delegate callback method in my ViewController

```
- (void)searchDidFinishWithResults:(NSArray *)results {
        NSLog(@"resultsList: %i", [results count]);
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setResultsList:) withObject:results waitUntilDone:YES];
//    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}
```

I also have a log in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to check how many items are in my [results count].  When I look, I basically get `cellForRowAtIndexPath` called many times (say 1000-3000 based on what we are searching for), but then in my `searchDidFinishWithResults:` method, I get 1 item.  It's always `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that gets called, and then this `searchDidFinishWithResults:` method.  So after I update the model, the table doesn't update again and I'm not sure why.  I thought I could manually call `reloadData`, but that gives me the same results.

So a more concrete example of what get's logged is this:

```
resultsList: 2909 (I type in one key, and only this gets logged)
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 2909 (my second key in the search bar, this gets logged)
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 2909
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 2909
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 2909
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 2909
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 2909
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 2909
resultsList: 1370 (this is the last thing that gets logged when my 2nd key is pressed)
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 1370 (this is the first thing that gets logged when my 3rd key is pressed)
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 1370
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 1370
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 1370
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 1370
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 1370
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] 1370
resultsList: 1 (last thing that gets logged when my 3rd key is pressed)
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.  reloadData does work.  Problem was I was trying to call

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
```

instead of

```
[self.SearchController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
```